# Is there a secret way to control how -webkit-line-clamp handles links?

Tags: html, css, webkit

Consider you want to clamp a heading with a link to a certain amount of lines. When line-clamping links, Chrome tends to put the ellipses a bit sooner and end with the last portion of the link text. The only way I've found to avoid this is by either wrapping the link around the heading and only clamping the heading, or by adding a span inside the link and clamping that.

See this fiddle for a few examples: http://jsfiddle.net/eejwu0hf/4/

The setup is basically like this:

```
<head><style>
.box { width: 22%; float: left; margin: 0 1.5%; }
.clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style></head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h2><a class="clamp" href="#">Some title that could do with some clamping, because look, it just keeps on going and going there's no end to it, or at least not one I can see coming up any time shortly.</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2 class="clamp"><a href="#">Some title that could do with some clamping, because look, it just keeps on going and going there's no end to it, or at least not one I can see coming up any time shortly.</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#"><h2 class="clamp">Some title that could do with some clamping, because look, it just keeps on going and going there's no end to it, or at least not one I can see coming up any time shortly.</h2></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2><a href="#"><span class="clamp">Some title that could do with some clamping, because look, it just keeps on going and going there's no end to it, or at least not one I can see coming up any time shortly.</span></a></h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

You will notice that the first 2 examples have "Some title... time shortly" whereas the second 2 will be more like "Some title that could do...".

Is there any hidden property that controls this and has a different default value on links than any other elements?